# Undetermined form of limits

Tags: limits

i have to find the solution of 
limit of $\sin(x)^{\arcsin(x)}$ as $x$ approaches $0$.
i have been trying a lot of different ways on how to find the solution of it but none of them helped me.

I tried to turn it into $0/0$ form and use l'hopital's rule since its the form $0^0$ but i am stuck and i can not proceed it anymore.

i did this 
$f(x)=\sin(x)$,
$g(x)=\arcsin(x)$
turned it like this

$\exp\left(\arcsin(x)/(1/\ln(\sin(x)))\right)$ as x approaches $0$ but no result

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\sin x ^ {\arcsin x} $$

$$ \ln y = \arcsin x. \ln \sin x = \frac {\ln \sin x}{\frac {1}{\arcsin x}}$$

Now apply L.Hospital Rule and you will get $$\lim_{x\to 0}  \ln y =0$$ which gives you the $\lim_{x\to 0} y=1$

Comment: this was really helpful,and clear ... i really appreciate it ...a thousand thanks 

Comment: Thanks for your attention and understanding

Answer (score 0):

Folowing your idea

$$\sin x ^ {\arcsin x}=e^{\arcsin x\log (\sin x)}\to e^0=1$$

indeed

$$\arcsin x\log (\sin x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\frac x{\sin x}\cdot \sin x\cdot\log (\sin x)\to 1\cdot 1 \cdot 0=0$$

As an alternative we have that

$$\sin x ^ {\arcsin x}=\left[(\sin x)^{\sin x}\right] ^ {\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\frac{x}{\sin x}}\to 1^1=1$$

indeed by $t=\sin x \to 0$ we have that $(\sin x)^{\sin x}=t^t \to 1$.